# How to search for a value with quotation marks in sql column and replace it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my sql table i have a column where i have values like :

[image]

I need to find these type of entries and remove single quotes as i dont need them, but how to fetch them through query in where clause ?
If i use select * from table 1 where desc = 'the values is '10', it simply wont work as the statement is not correct. 
how can i modify my where clause to get desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double the quotation mark to escape it :

```
select * from table 1 where desc = 'i am ''not'' a graduate'
```

As a side note, don’t select `*`, explicitly list the columns you are interested in:

```
select id, "desc" from table 1 where desc = 'i am ''not'' a graduate'
```

… And don’t name your columns with SQL reserved words ;-)

Comment: Also escape the word `desc` it is a reserved work, either `[desc]` or `"desc"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
select * from table 1 where desc like '%'%'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try to use different quote types (double and single) inside and outside value. for example

```
SELECT * FROM table 1 WHERE desc = "the values is '10'";
```

or find all rows at once which contain single quote in desc

```
SELECT * FROM table 1 WHERE desc LIKE "%'%";
```