# How do I search for words *including* quotation marks in Access/SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, quotation-marks

I need to distinguish ‘"Omreisende"’ from ‘Omreisende’ in an SQL search. How do I write such a query? The solutions I have found thus far (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700114/how-to-search-for-a-value-with-quotation-marks-in-sql-column-and-replace-it)), specifically try to circumvent the quotation mark, whereas I need to differentiate strings with them from those without them.

MS Access 2007 running towards an Oracle server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Chr(34) ` is equivalent of `"` if you're using a macro. So it will be `Chr(34)  & Omreisende & Chr(34) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS-Access you need to do it like this:

[Quotation Marks in Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258154(v=office.12).aspx)

```
[LastName] = """strName"""
```

In Oracle:
[Quotation Marks in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315340/pl-sql-how-to-escape-single-quote-in-a-string)

```
[LastName] = '''strName'''
```

So in MS-Access the Escape-operator is the double quotes `"` and in Oracle it is the single qoutes `'`